# Python, pandas and NLP: creating a corpus by dividing text based on value in other column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm quite new to "coding" in general, and Python in particular, so bear with me!

I have a CSV file that has feedback gathered from a feedback form on a web site (a "Was this page useful" feedback form. The CSV has one row per feedback received. There are several columns, but the ones that I'M interested in in this case are:
- 'What's wrong' (populated by a selection from a list by the user - limited number of possible values)
-'Details' (text typed in - the actuations feedback)
- 'Topic' (manually entered by reviewers of the feedback - hoping to eventually automate this through classification, but not there yet - the possible values here are potentially limitless

I made a pandas data frame out of this CSV.

I want to create a corpus to run some NLP algorithms (TF-IDF, for example). I want to stitch together all the text from the "Details" column, based the value of the 'What's wrong' and-or the 'Topic' column. Basically, the corpus would have one document per 'value' present in the Topic column, comprised of the text from all rows that have this value.

My initial thinking would be something like this:
- create a dictionary
- iterate over the values in the 'Topic' column, and create a key for each of the value found in that list
- iterate over each row - if value X is in the the 'Topic' column, append the string from the 'Details' cell in the value for key X in the dictionary

I'm not too sure how to code that, or if there would be a better way to do this...

Data looks like this:
[Dataframe with 3 columns: 'Ref number', 'Details', and 'Topic'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIFeG.png)

What I want is to automatically create "documents", stitching together all the strings from the Detail column that have the same label in the "Topic" column. The list of topics will be changing, so I won't know in advance the number of documents to create (and the exact names of the different topics).

This creates the dictionary:

```
dict = {}        
for topic in data_cropped['Topic'].unique():
       dict[topic] = []
```

And then I'm stuck to try to join the string from 'Details' in dict[topic], if value from 'Topic' is equal to the key.

I tried this:

```
for text in data_cropped['Details']:
       if data_cropped['Topic'] in dict.keys():
                dict[key] = dict[key].append(text)
```

But I get a this error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you illustrate this with an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added some details in the question (and pic of what the data looks like).

Comment: Updating the question again as I figured the first part (creating a dictionary with a key for all the unique labels), but I'm still having issues with populating the value of each key based on which value is in the Details column.

Comment: Could you provide a small excerpt of the dataframe as text, and an example output that you expect, please? This should guarantee we understand what you expect the code to do and also easier for us to test our code before posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its the fastest way but you could do something like:

```py
topic_dict = {}
for topic, topic_df in data_cropped.groupby('Topic'):
    topic_dict[topic] = ' '.join(topic_df['Details'].tolist())
```

Comment: This worked! I also had found this solution, but it was more complicated. Thanks!

`for key in dict.keys():
        dict[key] = data_cropped.loc[data_cropped['Topic'] == key]['Details'].values
for value in dict:
       dict[value] = set(dict[value])`

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you mark this as a correct answer? I like internet points haha.